# How to bind a Control to <ItemTemplate> in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Edit: My object is defined as below. I passed it into GridView1.

```
public class UserTestorViewModel
{
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
    public Label SuiteName {get;set;}
}
```

I have GridView bound to a customized `List<UserTestorViewModel>`:

```
this.GridView1.DataSource = utViewModelList;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

and in the .aspx I have

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LoginName">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="LoginName" runat= "server" Text= '<%# ((ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel)Container.DataItem).User.userName %> '></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

this works because `ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel.User.userName` is string, but

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SuiteName">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# ((ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel)Container.DataItem).SuiteName %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

because `ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel.SuiteName` is Label from `System.Web.UI.WebControls`

So how to bind a `System.Web.UI.WebControls` to `<ItemTemplate>` NOT the Text of the `System.Web.UI.WebControls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may place a Placeholder control in ItemTemplate and put your label control to it on the RowCreated event of the GridView:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowCreated);
    }

    void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var dataItem = (KeyValuePair<int, Label>)e.Row.DataItem;
            var nameLabelPlaceholder = e.Row.FindControl("NameLabelPlaceholder") as PlaceHolder;
            if (nameLabelPlaceholder != null)
            {
                nameLabelPlaceholder.Controls.Add(dataItem.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = GetGridViewDataSource();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private object GetGridViewDataSource()
    {
        return (from item in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                select new KeyValuePair<int, Label>(item, new Label() { ID = string.Format("NameLabel_{0}", item), Text = string.Format("Item #{0}", item), ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red }))
                    .ToDictionary(kvp1 => kvp1.Key, kvp2 => kvp2.Value);
    }


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Key">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="Key" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="NameLabelPlaceholder" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: That's almost what I want. But I already passed the `Label` into GridView1 when `this.GridView1.DataSource = utViewModelList;`. How to get it when `GridView1_RowCreated` you provided. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote `var dataItem = e.Row.DataItem;`. In debug mode I saw that dataItem was what I passed into the GridView and what I was looking for. But why cannot I use `dataItem.SuiteName`?

Comment: Of course, you can but as the e.Row.DataItem's type is System.Object, you must cast it to your type (ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel)